# High Voltage Capacitor Lead Clearance

Tags: pcb-design, high-voltage, clearance, creepage, ipc

I am designing a high voltage board, 10,000 VDC. I wish to use a suitably rated capacitor such as the `DHR4E4A102K2BB`. When I have been studying the `IPC-2221` and `IEC 61010` standards the conductor clearance should be in the order of *0.00305 mm/volt*, therefore you would think that for a 10kV rated capacitor the lead spacing should be at least 30.5mm.

However, when looking at many datasheets they are around 9.5mm +/-2mm.

[image]

In my application one lead needs to be at 10kV and the other at 0V, so I would expect arcing/flash over to occur.

What am I missing?

**EDIT TO SHOW PCB**

Here is what I have so far with the PCB which shows the capacitor and slots (yellow line is board edge/routing)
[image]

**EDIT TO SHOW SCHEMATIC**

Schematic added to show that is I added DC grading resistors in parallel to the capacitor then it would create a potential divider network and my outputs would be less than 10kV. Hence the discussion about `headroom`. I have 10kV coming in and I need 10kV (or there abouts) going out.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these components is unsuitable for continuous high voltage. On top of what @Spehro said, creepage will be impossible without immersing it in transformer oil and I would not be allowed to put more than about 3 kV across that 7.5 mm lead spacing, but that could be slightly more in your case depending on company policy, altitude range for the product, humidity and pollution degree of the environment. (pollution degree would normally just relate to creepage)

What you normally end up with when using components intended for consumer electronics or light industrial use is to derate them and end up with a series-parallel array of them. Be aware of capacitor tolerance and calculate your maximum misdistribution and make sure you have rating accordingly.

Source: high voltage design engineer for the past five+ years.

EDIT: Here is a schematic and transient simulation for you. I don't know your load nor why you have 5 Mohm output resistance, so there are several assumptions here. This is absolute worst case scenario for +-10 % resistors (47 Mohm) and +-20 % capacitors (1 nF). If you are hand-building it, you can probably hand-tune each value to match much better than that. 
[image]

Comment: So your suggestion is to place multiple lower rated capacitors in series, thus increasing the clearance and creepage between the HV on the first cap lead and the 0V on the final cap lead? Nice idea.
I did not follow this part `Be aware of capacitor tolerance and calculate your maximum misdistribution and make sure you have eating accordingly. `

Comment: Yes, that’s correct. If you connect two in series, you are NOT guaranteed to have half the voltage across each. If the capacitors are +-20 % tolerance, you must assume +20 % one one and -20 % on the other, and the one with the lower capacitance will see significantly higher voltage for any AC signal. For DC, it’s only the leakage which determines the distribution, and it’s almost never guaranteed. You must add grading resistors in parallel, but they will be subject to the same mis-distribution. High voltage is not easy and nothing will work your way by itself!

Comment: Excellent advice. Would parallel grading resistors not act as a potential divider? I am designing a simple RC network, so have a 5M ohm in series with the capacitor which connects to ground. The grading resistors would form a divider, no?

Comment: That’s the purpose. For DC, your resistors sets the division ratio. For AC, your capacitors sets your division ratio. Please do calculate your worst case voltage stress for both DC and AC with maximum tolerance.

Comment: The problem is I have no headroom for division. The PSU is 10kV and we are expecting 10kV out. We have an RC network. It goes in series with a 5 M ohm resistor (2 x 10M in parallel) and a 1nF capacitor to ground.

Comment: Please explain headroom since it can have several meanings. Can you draw a simplified schematic?

Comment: schematic with notes added as an edit.

Comment: Oh, so your 5 Megaohm would form a divider with your grading resistors? How much parasitic loss/voltage drop can you tolerate?

Comment: I would guess 10%.... Can you show me a schematic with the series capacitors and grading resistors?

Comment: I’m mobile and away on holiday. Can you make do until Monday and I will prepare a schematic and simulation for you?

Comment: Sure. Any help however timely is much appreciated :-)

Comment: @tomdertech Schematic updated for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Breakdown voltage of air is about 3kV/mm so it won't typically break down. The requirement for creepage for good design is more than that, so you can route an unplated slot between the pins. That takes care of the PCB design.

You still have the creepage distance over the capacitor surface to contend with- it's probably not adequate unless you coat the board or pot the circuit.

By the way, that Murata part has a [final order date](https://www.ttieurope.com/content/dam/ttiinc/products/PCN/Murata/Murata-Obsolescence-PCN-00002456.pdf) of 'September 2019, meaning it is marked to be permanently discontinued.

Comment: I have removed most of the FR4 between the pads. So are you saying that the capacitor voltage is not rated for its own creepage distance? Where would I coat the board?

Comment: The slot can be long. You could put conformal coating on the board + capacitor (after assembly, obviously).

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the PCB I currently have with the slots.